# Floating Placeholder

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, frontend, user-experience

I am trying to implement floating label for the forms on my page.

I referred a couple of sources and came across this link in codepen and Fiddle.

I could implement this but these approaches needs re doing all the forms as I need wrap the input field in a div or a fieldset and add labels. Is there a way to do that using jQuery and targeting the placeholder directly?

I understand the question is very high level. My apologies.

Comment: http://codepen.io/iamjordanlittle/pen/AHdfn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a jQuery solution here for you - all it will require is that you add a 'placeholder="placeHolderTextGoesHere"' attribute to each form element.

```
$("input").each(function(e){

    $(this).wrap('<fieldset></fieldset>');
    var tag = $(this).attr("placeholder");
    $(this).attr("placeholder","");
    $(this).after('<label for="name">'+tag+'</label>');
});
```

What we are doing is finding all the inputs - wrapping them in a fieldset and then adding a label after - we use the placeholder tag as a fall-back for none-JS visitors and set it to "" if JS is allowed after grabbing its value.

```js
$("input").each(function(e) {
  $(this).wrap('<fieldset></fieldset>');
  var tag = $(this).attr("placeholder");
  //var tag= $(this).data("tag");
  $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
  $(this).after('<label for="name">' + tag + '</label>');
});

$('input').on('blur', function() {
  if (!$(this).val() == "") {
    $(this).next().addClass('stay');
  } else {
    $(this).next().removeClass('stay');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
}
form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 30em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
input {
  width: 20em;
  padding: 1em 1em .8em 1em;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: #fbfbe9;
}
input + label {
  display: block;
  cursor: text;
  color: #777;
  transition: .15s ease-out all;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.8em;
  left: 2.3em;
}
input:focus + label,
label.stay {
  top: 1em;
  left: 3em;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #139dd7;
  transition: .15s ease-out all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="" id="name" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="" id="email" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank is very close to what I want with minimal change to exisitng code (CSS for fieldset class). Thanks.